# I`m using an Environment texture that looks fine with normal focal length but when I make viewport/camera bigger values it`s too big, can`t tweak it

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, world

Say, when I use 250 mm, the Environment texture in World looks too close and distorted, but I can`t make it more distant as if I use scaling in Mapping node, it just distorts the texture more but doesn not do what I need, any advice? I need that focal length but with less distorted environment texture.

I`m doing this in Eevee.

The 1-st picture is what I get with long focal length setting.
The 2-nd is how I`d like it to look at chosen focal length

[image: That`s how it looks with long focal length]

[image: Thats how Id like it to look at chosen focal length]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing your world shader settings?

Comment: yes, I updated.